# How to keep population happy?

Tags: endless-legend

All my towns' approval gauges are dropping for some reason, but I just can't understand why.  Actually, I don't know how I'm supposed to keep population happy and avoid rebellion.

Any idea ?

[image: Approval gauge]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [this Steam thread](http://steamcommunity.com/app/289130/discussions/0/540739861834901559/#c540739861838556882):

> - Level up districts (city expansion tile) and cities instead of making lines of unleveled districts.
>     To level a district or a city, surround it with 4 other districts
> - Research +approval technologies and buildings
> - Use luxury goods that improve approval
> - Use influence for approval kingdom bonus

In addition to that, some anomalies like the spiral rock peel will provide approval bonuses.

[image: spiral rock peel anomaly]

Comment: Do you have to have your city extended to encompass the 'Spiral Rock Peel' in order for it to take effect? Or does it apply as soon as you control the region it is in?

Comment: You need the tile to be built (first solution) ;)  See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/165958/15726

Comment: +1 leveling up districts and +approval buildings are the main, consistent ways to deal with this

Answer (score 6):

You are expanding too fast. The -60 Approval lists "From Expansion Disaprroval", which increases with each city.

You'll have to stop generating new cities and invest in Aprroval bonuses if you want your cities to be productive (since Rebellion results in a huge drop in production of all things).

Comment: Damn...  Should I destroy some of my most unproductive cities in order to get approval back into green ?

Comment: Also: are there any indicators that warn me about that ?  How can I know when building new cities will start decreasing approval ?